# React Native FlatList row alignment issue

Tags: reactjs, list, react-native, react-hooks, rxjs

I am using a FlatList to render an array on the screen. It works fine exception for one use case. The issue I am having is that when I have less than 4 items in a row then it renders differently.

Here is an example. I have 2 items in the second row. I would like it to fill the first two columns but it fills the first and third column.

[image]

What am I doing wrong here?

```
const data = [
    {id:1, title: 'Option 1', image: require('../../assets/empty-profile-picture.jpeg')},
    {id:1, title: 'Option 2', image: require('../../assets/empty-profile-picture.jpeg')},
    {id:2, title: 'Option 3', image: require('../../assets/empty-profile-picture.jpeg')},
    {id:3, title: 'Option 4', image: require('../../assets/empty-profile-picture.jpeg')},
    {id:4, title: 'Option 4', image: require('../../assets/empty-profile-picture.jpeg')},
    {id:5, title: 'Option 4', image: require('../../assets/empty-profile-picture.jpeg')}
,  ];


<FlatList
    contentContainerStyle={{ justifyContent: 'space-between' }}
    data={data}
    numColumns={4}
    keyExtractor={(item) => item.id.toString() }
    renderItem={({item, index}) => {
    const lastItem = index === data.length - 1;
    return (
        <View style={{flex: 1, marginBottom: 20 }}>
            <Image style={styles.cardImage} source={item.image} />
            <Text style={styles.title}>{item.title}</Text>
        </View>
    );
    }}
/>
```

**EDIT**

Changing the bottom part to this:

```
<View style={{flex: 1, marginBottom: 20, alignItems: 'flex-end', }}>
      <Image style={styles(theme).cardImage} source={item.image} />
      <Text style={styles(theme).title}>{item.title}</Text>
</View>
```

does seem to have some effect on the row and look this:

[image]

Comment: Because you have  `space-between`

Comment: @Dominic tried without it too... same result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why this happens is `numColumns={4}`. The `FlatList` component tries to split its data items evenly on `4 columns`. The number `6` is not evenly divisible by `4`. The remainder is `2`, so it makes room for two components that use the same space as the others.

You can think of it as a grid. First, the number of items are calculated (in this case 6), then it is determined how many rows are needed (in this case 2). In summary, we get a `2x4 grid` and each cell in this grid gets the same amount of space. Second, it tries to distribute the actual items evenly among free cells, alternating empty cells and actually occupied cells. If we have 5 items instead of 6, you will notice, that it looks like you want.

**Solution:** I haven't found an elegant solution to this issue, i.e. some simple prop that we could use. However, we can calculate this ourselves and add a dummy view.

```js
export default function App() {
  const dummyItemCount = array.length % 4
  const [data, setData] = useState(dummyItemCount > 0 ? [...array, ...[...new Array(dummyItemCount).keys()].map((_, idx) => ({id: array.length + idx}))] : array)

  return (
    <FlatList
    contentContainerStyle={{ justifyContent: 'space-between' }}
    data={data}
    numColumns={4}
    keyExtractor={(item) => item.id.toString() }
    renderItem={({item, index}) => {
        return (
         item.image ? <View style={{flex: 1, marginBottom: 20 }}>
            {item.image}
            <Text>{item.title}</Text>
          </View> : <View /> 
        );
    }}
  />
  );
}
```

I have created a dummy array for testing:

```js
const array = [
    {id:1, title: 'Option 1', image: <View style={{height: 20, width: 20, backgroundColor: "red"}}/>},
    {id:2, title: 'Option 2', image: <View style={{height: 20, width: 20, backgroundColor: "red"}}/>},
    {id:3, title: 'Option 3', image: <View style={{height: 20, width: 20, backgroundColor: "red"}}/>},
    {id:4, title: 'Option 4', image: <View style={{height: 20, width: 20, backgroundColor: "red"}}/>},
    {id:5, title: 'Option 5', image: <View style={{height: 20, width: 20, backgroundColor: "red"}}/>},
    {id:6, title: 'Option 6', image: <View style={{height: 20, width: 20, backgroundColor: "red"}}/>},
 ];
```

The result is as follows and works dynamically for any number of elements.

[image]

[Here is a little snack for testing](https://snack.expo.dev/@pgrepds/trembling-banana).

Comment: Wow, adding a new object to the ArrayList was the main trick. Thank you for saving my day!!

Answer (score 0):

Here is the tweak.

- container of flatlist should have flex = number of columns in flatlist.
- each item should have limit for width so that it should not expand automatically to occupy the empty space.

suppose if we have 4 columns in flatlist
`<Flatlist column={4}....`

then our style should be like this:

```js
container:{
    flex:4,  // Flatlist column 
    flexDirection: 'row',
},
item:{
    flex:1,
    maxWidth: "25%", // 1/4 
}
```

Display orientation : vertical
[image: screenshot of flex grid in react native]

Display orientation : horizontal
[image: screenshot of flex grid in react native]

Answer (score -2):

Remove **justifyContent: 'space-between'** inside the **contentContainerStyle**
for the spacing style apply on the main view of the return()
try them may be it's working as per your requirement.

```
<FlatList
   data={data}
   numColumns={4}
   keyExtractor={(item) => item.id.toString() }
   renderItem={({item, index}) => {
   const lastItem = index === data.length - 1;
   return (
       <View style={{flex: 1, marginBottom: 20 }}> //apply spacing style
       <Image style={styles.cardImage} source={item.image} />
       <Text style={styles.title}>{item.title}</Text>
       </View>
   );
   }}
/>
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to work

Comment: apply marginRight to the View